# How can I listen to MongoDB collection inserts/updates without .watch()?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a MongoDB database which isn't sharded or replicated (and I can't change that for this task). How can I listen to inserts and updates to collection, as I can't use `.watch()`?

I've tried to use `.aggregate()`, like this (I use Node.js and Mongoose), but it doesn't work:

```
const changeStream = Model.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { operationType: { $in: ['insert', 'update'] } } },
  { $sort: { clusterTime: 1 } }
]);

changeStream.on('data', (change) => {
  console.log(change);
});

changeStream.on('error', (error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Watching/change streams work by monitoring the oplog which captures the writes to documents sent by clients. If you have a standalone environment (namely one that is running without --replSet even if just a single member/process) then there is nothing to 'watch'. Said another way more succinctly: I don't think you can achieve what you want directly and would need to implement an entire tracking system on your own

Comment: Perhaps one of [`mongoose`'s _debugging_ options](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/faq.html#enable_debugging) might help.

Comment: In the past, people would tail the oplog, but MongoDB started to add operations to the oplog that are deemed internal and require special handling and provisioning.  This pattern continued over the last X number of releases to the point where you need to be an expert to properly tail the oplog.  As a result, MongoDB provided a wrapper utility that provides the original functionality but handles all internal operations.  This utility of course is change streams.  Either way the Oplog is only available when turning on replication.  You could convert a standalone to a single node replica set, no?